# Returning Groupedby distinct linq values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DataTable that looks like

```
Agency          | Contact         | Group
Agency1           person1           lunch runners
Agency1           person1           band
Agency1           person3           basketball
Agency2           person4           band
```

and I would like to group them by agency, and then by contact name. I have tried using linq 50 different ways but have hit  a wall. Can someone shed a little light? thanks.

Comment: What would be your expected output ?

Comment: Can you show your best try?

Comment: What do you mean by agency *and then by contract name* ? It sounds like ordering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an anonymous type:

```
var groups = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new 
        { 
            Agency  = r.Field<string>("Agency"),
            Contact = r.Field<string>("Contact") 
        });

foreach (var agencyContactGroup in groups)
   Console.WriteLine("Agency: {0} Contact: {1} Groups: {2} Count: {3}"
       , agencyContactGroup.Key.Agency
       , agencyContactGroup.Key.Contact
       , string.Join(",", agencyContactGroup.Select(r => r.Field<string>("Group")))
       , agencyContactGroup.Count());
```

Output with your sample data:

```
Agency: Agency1 Contact: person1 Groups: lunch runners,band Count: 2
Agency: Agency1 Contact: person3 Groups: basketball         Count: 1
Agency: Agency2 Contact: person4 Groups: band               Count: 1
```

Comment: using the foreach, how would i add those to a datatable?

Comment: I am binding to a repeater to a datatable.

Comment: You cannot derive a `DataTable` from an `IEnumerable<anonymoustype>` easily. But what's the desired result from the query at all? If you want to take a specific row from each group you could create a new table with `CopyToDataTable`. Otherwise you could create a `List<YourCustomtype>`. You could also use this anonymous type as `DataSource` for the `Repeater` directly. If i remember correctly you need a collection, so use `ToList()` at the end.

Comment: Does it look like I am adding that to the list correctly, i set up properties for the Agency, Contact and groups. But it still doesn't return a distinct display.

Comment: @jpavlov: Perhaps you should edit your question and show what you expect. Apart from that, you can add `ToList()` behind the `GroupBy` to create a list.

Comment: Thanks, I am a little burnt out, but you helped me get it going. Thanks Tim Schmelter!

Answer (score 0):

`collection.GroupBy(x => new { x.Agency, x.Contact })` should do it. This creates an anonymous object that is used for the key.

Note that you'll have to apply this general idea to the DataTable as @TimSchmelter does in his answer.

If you need a hierarchy of groups (i.e. the Agency1 group has a person1 group inside) you would do this:

```
collection.GroupBy(x => x.Agency).Select(x => x.GroupBy(y => y.Contact));
```

Comment: I don't think this is a correct interpretation of the question. You are grouping contact names by agency, not grouping by agency then by contact name.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi I made an edit that should address your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = db.<EntityCollection>
    .ToLookup(a => a.Agency)
    .ToDictionary( lu => lu.Key, lu => lu.ToLookup( lui => lui.Contact ) );
```

Can then be accessed as follows:

```
results[<agencyName>][<contactName>]
```

Comment: this is an algorithm to group groups.  apply it to what you will